# Uncheck all values in dynamically populated CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm populating a CheckBoxList from database table. As per requirement, all the values should be unchecked be default. Even though I have written code to do the same, first value always is checked, and I can't figure out why. Here's the code:

```
for (int i = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    CheckBoxList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
while (rd.Read())
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(rd["FullName"]), Convert.ToString(rd["ContactID"]));
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
}
con.Close();
for (int i = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = false;
```

Once the page is posted back, only then all the values are unchecked. 
Any help and suggestions are most welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of **UpdatePanel**. Once I removed that, code started working without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
  CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Checked = false;

Comment: Can't use this as it gives error: "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' could be found "

Comment: or try to put the method in the Pre_Init or Pre_render method

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem class does not have the property checked, right click resolve does not work.

Comment: CheckBoxList1 is not defined in PreInit, it's null.

Comment: can u show me how you created the checkbox list and added it to the markup?

Comment: Checkbox is defined statically, only populated dynamically. <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Height="50"  BackColor="#b6b7bc" RepeatColumns="3"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
          >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: add  AutoPostBack="True" in the markup <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Height="50" BackColor="#b6b7bc" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" >

Comment: i built the code myself and it worked here.. ive made a method: protected void blabla(){} and put the method name blabla(); in page_load();, worked..

Comment: Oh, then I am even more confused. Why is it not working at my end?

Comment: I have tried debugging. After setting the values, if I read, they are correct (all false) I'll try again and get back. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = false;
```

Just a thought, but; is this loop really working? Because your stop condition is when i is greater than 0. That should be true from the beginning of the loop. I think your stop condition should be i=0.

And like bdz says, use items[].checked instead.

Comment: The loop is working, if the number of items is 4, i goes from 3 to 0.

Comment: Ok, I think that's strange, but great :)
Does it work with items[].checked?

Comment: No :-( Checked is not defined on ListItem

Comment: It shouldn't actually... ;) I'm reading the docs right now and item[].selected should work. I think. Try to loop the different way, that is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: This is a really old post, but maybe it can help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8105/ASP-NET-C-Disable-Enable-ListItems

Comment: This post is good if we want to do on client side, but doesn't really help the code we are discussing. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this section of yours:

```
 for (int i = CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = false;
```

in to this:

```
 foreach(ListItem i in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
     i.Selected = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CheckBoxList1.ClearSelection()**

This works on Asp.Net Framework 4.5
I have not tried it on other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int index in this.CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
{
    this.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, false);
}
```